# Four process execute slower than two process

Tags: c, linux, parallel-processing

I want to compare the matrix multiplication using different process(1, 2 ,4)

I use the code for 2 process, fork once, and let child the parent and do the 1/2 calculation

```
  if (cpid == 0) {            /* Code executed by child */
      for (int i = 0; i < dimension / 2; i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++)
        {
          //matrix multiplication
        }
      }
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  } else {                    /* Code executed by parent */
        for (int i = dimension / 2; i < dimension; i++)
        {
              for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++)
              {
          //matrix multiplication                    
              }
        }
  }
```

and the code for 4 process, fork once, and then child and parent fork again,
use the 4 process to do 1/4 calculation

```
 cpid = fork();
  if (cpid == 0)
  {
      cpid = fork();
      if (cpid == 0)
      {
              for (int i = 0; i < dimension / 2; i++)
              {
                for (int j = 0; j < dimension / 2; j++)
                {
                  //matrix multiplication
                }
              }
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
      }
      else{
              for (int i = 0; i < dimension / 2; i++)
              {
                for (int j = dimension / 2; j < dimension; j++)
                {
                  //matrix multiplication
                }
              }
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
      }
  }
  else{
      cpid = fork();
      if (cpid == 0)
      {
              for (int i = dimension / 2; i < dimension; i++)
              {
                for (int j = 0; j < dimension / 2; j++)
                {
                  //matrix multiplication
                }
              }
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
      }
      else{
              for (int i = dimension / 2; i < dimension; i++)
              {
                for (int j = dimension / 2; j < dimension; j++)
                {
                  //matrix multiplication
                }
              }
      }      
  }
```

the full code is:http://codepad.org/MmjRiBIN

and to my surprise is that the speed is 2 > 4 > 1 .

```
1
elapsed 5147.936000 ms
2
elapsed 2821.225000 ms
4
elapsed 3129.096000 ms
```

I cannot figure out it.

Comment: According to codepad it doesn't compile ;-) What impact does the shared memory between all the processes have?

Comment: How many cores do you have to process this? And what architecture is it?

Comment: I am using the macbook air 2013 and the parllel desktop with ubuntu 13.10. I have setting the parall desktop virtual machine using 4 cores, but I don't know it will affect or not.

Comment: I have compiled it with g++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you are running on a dual core.
Splitting the workload thorough various processes only helps if you have cores to work with each of the processes.
Otherwise the processor cores will spend time switching the process context instead of working on the task itself.

Your problem may also be too small and the overhead of using parallel processing overcomes its benefit. If this is the case, running 4 processes with bigger matrices will eventually be more performant than the 1 and 2 processes version.

Comment: I am using the macbook air 2013 and the parllel desktop with ubuntu 13.10. I have setting the parall desktop virtual machine using 4 cores, but I don't know it will affect or not.

Comment: hey @Liang-YuPan. What was the problem?